# Python 3.8: KeyError resulting from a referral to vars() within a function... Even though the variable is clearly there and accessible

Tags: python, variables, keyerror

context: I have global variables ids1, ids2, ids3, ids4 and ids5.

When I attempt to execute this function

```
def collect_id_sols(id_no):
    
    ids = vars()["ids" + str(id_no)]
    sols = vars()["sols" + str(id_no)]

    for line in range(0,len(ids)):

        #rest irrelevant...
```

The interpreter throws a:

```
  File "sols_from_ids.py", line 112, in <module>
    collect_id_sols(1)
  File "sols_from_ids.py", line 78, in collect_id_sols
    ids = vars()["ids" + str(id_no)]
KeyError: 'ids1'
```

i.e. what it's telling me is that there is no such key "ids1".

However, the variable is CLEARLY existing and completely accessible.
Right after this error is thrown, if I do a `>>>ids1` or `>>>vars()["ids1"]` within the interpreter, everything shows and works just as it should be.

What's going on? :(

P.S. And, of course, the global variables are declared and assigned *before* the function definition and call.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). Is there any reason why you aren't using a single list or dictionary called `ids`? Also, in the local scope, `vars()` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: ```>Also, in the local scope, vars() isn't what you think it is.\n```

You are correct. I eventually fixed my issue by using globals() instead. Yay! :)

Answer (score 1):

[vars](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#vars) returns a dictionary giving the *local* scope, so it wouldn't know about these non-local variables. While there are ways (e.g. with `globals()`) to do what you want to do, a much better solution is to use a proper data structure such as a list or dictionary for your ids. Anytime you find yourself trying to iterate over a collection of variables which differ only by a number tacked onto the end, there is a data structure waiting to be born.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python docs, `vars()` used without an argument acts like `locals()`, i.e. :
`Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.`

So when you use 'vars()' in your function block, it will return the symbol table of within the function block, which will be empty in your case. So you get a Key Error.

Using vars()["something"] to access the variable `something` only works at module-level, not inside functions or classes. Plus it is not a viable thing to do in my opinion.

What you probably want to do here is to use an array to store your variables idsX, where ids[1] will be ids1 etc. (or a dictionary)

Or you can have another function like :

```py
def getIds(number) :
    if number == 1 :
        return ids1
    elif number == 2 :
        return ids2
```

etc, and then in `collect_id_sols` you just do ids = getIds(id_no).